# Trying to draw too large bitmap

Tags: maui

I'm trying to add an .svg image in my MAUI app. But when it starts I get an error: Java.Lang.RuntimeException: 'Canvas: trying to draw too large(393850620bytes) bitmap.'

My image has the size 4495x3179 pixels. How can I fix this error without resizing the image?

Comment: `4495x3179` is really big for a mobile device.  Why can't you resize it?

Comment: It's a building's map. I want to give user opportunity to zoom this image to take a closer look.

Comment: for a diagram I would try displaying the SVG natively rather than allowing MAUI to convert it to a raster image

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Let me answer the bot, instead of you: <Image Source="test.png">, where test.png is 4495x3179 (svg or png, it does not matter).

Comment: @hills I say split it. It can handle about 1/4 of this size. Make it as map tiles. It will be much easier to make.

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, this could be a known issue that being tracked in the link below, you can follow up there.

https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/11230

Since hardware acceleration is enabled by default and you can try to set `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` to disable it in the manifest file, the issue would disappear. However, it is not recommended to force that in the MAUI application.

Add the following attribute to the tag to disable hardware acceleration for your entire MAUI application:

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="false" ...>
```